# Eclipse Outline view is hiding code

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-kepler, outline-view

I'm using the Kepler CDT release (4.3.1) of Eclipse. When I click on anything in the Outline view, the corresponding editor view is reduced to showing just that item. If I click on a variable, I get a single line with just that variable. The Edit->Expand Selection options are all dimmed out. Hitting Shift-Alt-Up Arrow just moves me up to the previous item in the outline view. If I change editor tabs and come back then the Expand Selection options enable and I can manually hit Shift-Alt-Up Arrow a number of times to make the entire file visible again but clicking on anything in the outline view again will just reduce the view. Is there some new setting in Kepler that will make outline stop doing this?

Comment: Could it be that Mylyn 'focus on active task' is on?

Comment: I did my best to exonerate Mylyn. The icon is currently always dimmed. Even so I went into the prefs and turned off everything I could find related to it. I wouldn't think Mylyn would filter down at the outline level anyway but it's a good thought in case it's going wonky. I don't see an easy way to uninstall Mylyn. Under Installed Software->Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers->EPP CPP Feature->Mylyn* the Uninstall... button stays disabled for all choices.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the feature for `Show Source of Selected Element Only` was turned on. In Kepler the toolbar button for this is not visible. Even searching under quick access doesn't turn it up so it's somewhat of a puzzle how it could have been turned on. I actually thought maybe it had been removed from Kepler.

In the `Customize Perspective` dialog under the `Tool Bar Visibility` tab. In the `Tool Bar Structure` section I opened the area for `Editor Presentation`. I noticed there was actually a check next to the box for `Show Source of Selected Element Only`. However, it wasn't visible in the toolbar (a bug I've seen before in Eclipse) so I unchecked it and checked it. Then I exited the dialog. Now the button showed up on the toolbar. I then toggled the feature on and then off. Now clicking in the outline view works correctly.just moves to the correct spot.